# Android: Why the bundle is always null?

Tags: android

I got an error that a number of users asked before here. I do not get the point and can't solve my problem with the former explanations.

That's the main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final String STATE_BLOC_NOTES = "STATE_BLOC_NOTES";
    static final String STATE_RECHERCHE = "RECHERCHE";
    BlocNotes monBlocNotes;
    EditText editTexteRechercheNotes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonAjouter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ajouterNote);
        TableLayout tableLayoutNotes = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableNote);
        editTexteRechercheNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rechercheNote);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            monBlocNotes = (BlocNotes)savedInstanceState.getParcelable(STATE_BLOC_NOTES);
            editTexteRechercheNotes.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_RECHERCHE));
        }else{
            monBlocNotes = new BlocNotes();
        }

        if(getIntent().hasExtra("nouvelleNote")) {
            Note nouvelleNote = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("nouvelleNote");
            monBlocNotes.ajouterNote(nouvelleNote);
        }

        for(Note n: monBlocNotes.getMesNotes()){
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);
            TextView textTitreNote = new TextView(this);

            textTitreNote.setText(n.getTitre() + " " + n.getDateModif());
            row.addView(textTitreNote);
            tableLayoutNotes.addView(row,lp);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(STATE_BLOC_NOTES, monBlocNotes);
        savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_RECHERCHE, editTexteRechercheNotes.getText().toString());

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        monBlocNotes = (BlocNotes)savedInstanceState.getParcelable(STATE_BLOC_NOTES);
        editTexteRechercheNotes.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_RECHERCHE));
    }

    public void ajouterUneNote(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NoteActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

I tried a few things but nothing in result.

Logcat:

```
02-05 21:32:13.384    1679-2274/com.google.process.gapps E/Backup﹕ [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2139)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2115)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:658)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.am.<init>(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.a.a(SourceFile:65)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.c.a(SourceFile:39)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:67)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:39)
        at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupAccountNotifierService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:76)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Add the error from logcat.

Comment: Well, the `Bundle` will only ever be not `null` when the activity undergoes a configuration change or is being recreated from a specific state after process termination (e.g., recent-tasks list). Are you testing using either of those?

Comment: I added the error from logcat. When I use "ajouterUneNote". I go to another activity and when i go back to this one I was expecting to still have my parcelable object "BlocNotes" and not create a new one but the bundle is always null.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be on the code of the MainActivity. Seems to be a configuration issue. Did you take a look here? http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html

Comment: if you test by changing orientation of your app, it will not null. sometimes the function is called but not always, as mentioned by Commonsware